# Haskell turning list of tuples into list of lists

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to turn a list of tuples into a list of lists. For example, if I have the list `[(9,1), (6,3), (4,1)]`, then this will turn into `[[9, 6, 4],[6],[6]]`. What's happening is that in the list of tuples `[(a,b)]`, `a` represents a number from 0-9 and `b` represents the occurrence of that number, `a` will always be unique.

What I am trying to do it go go over the list `n` times, where `n = maximum b in the list of tuples.` Each time I go over the list, I take `a` and put it into a list, then decrement `b` by 1. If `b == 0` then I just skip it.

So from my example, I take `[9,6,4]` and throw them into a list, then decrement the `b` of each of them, so now the list would look like `[(9,0),(6,2),(4,0)]`. Then going over again, I take `[6]`, list of tuples now looks like `[(9,0), (6,1), (4,0)]`. Finally, take `[6]` one last time, and now ever `b` in the list of tuples is `0` so it is done.

I have created a a function that takes the 1st element from the list of tuples iff `b` is >= 1, but I don't know how I can iterate this over the updated list with all `b - 1' for each tuple.

```
turnIntList :: [(Integer, Integer)] -> [[Integer]]
turnIntList [] = []
turnIntList x = ([map (\(a, b) -> case (a,b) of  _ | b >= 1 -> a | otherwise -> -1) x])
```

I have also tried creating another helper function that takes a list of tuples and will turn them into a list depending on how large `b` is. From the main function, I would try to send [(a, 1), (b, 1)...] to create the list, then keep track of decrementing `b` here until it's done. So, for this function:

```
pairingL :: [(Integer, Integer)] -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
pairingL ((a,b):xs) l -- = if b /= 0 then [a,b-1] else []
    | null xs = if b == 1 then [a] ++ l else if b > 1 then [a] ++ l ++ pairingL [(a,b-1)] l else l
    | otherwise = 
        if b /= 0 then [a] ++ l ++ pairingL ((a,b-1):xs) l else pairingL xs l


pairingL [(9,1), (7,2), (5,1)]
[9,7,7,5]

pairingL [(1,1), (2,1), (3,1)]
[1,2,3]

pairingL [(1,2), (2,2), (3,2)]
[1,1,2,2,3,3]
```

I've tried looking into unzipping the list and working with that, iteration, and repeat but I can't figure out how to get the function to go over the list multiple times and updating the list with the new `b` values then going again.

In conclusion, what I am trying to do is something like:

```
    turnIntList [(9,3),(5,1),(2,1)]
    [[9,5,2],[9],[9]]

    turnIntList [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1)]
    [[1,2,3,4]]

    turnIntList [(1,2),(2,2),(3,2)]
    [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

    turnIntList [(4,2),(6,1)]
    [[4,6],[4]]
```

**Process:**
I am taking the first element from the tuples, adding them to a list, then subtracting the second element by 1. After doing this for each tuple in the list, I repeat the process until all the second elements for each tuple is 0

Important notes: again, in the list of tuples [(a,b)], `a` will ALWAYS be UNIQUE number from 0-9, and `b >= 0`

Comment: Do you have some other examples for us?

Comment: @Elmex80s Sorry, I should have put more than 1 example. I added a few more and explained the process more clearly

Comment: Thanks. Input output is sufficient. First step in loop might be distracting

Comment: For your amusement, `turnIntList = transpose . map (uncurry (flip replicate))` works, too, though technically with signature `[(a, Int)] -> [[a]]` using `Int` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: Or even shorter, `turnIntList = (>>= uncurry (flip replicate))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This maybe

```
turnIntList :: [(Integer, Integer)] -> [[Integer]]
turnIntList [] = [] -- if it doesn’t compile use [[]]
turnIntList ls = [i | (i, _) <- ls] : turnIntList [(i, n - 1) | (i, n) <- ls, n - 1 > 0]
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a simpler solution with list comprehensions. I'm pretty new to Haskell and that is one of the areas I am still pretty weak on. Will definitely be reading up on it more. One thing I don't understand, I would imagine this would throw a `n` not in scope error since it isn't explicitly declared anywhere, however this works perfectly.

Comment: `n` is bound by the pattern match of the inner list comprehension @WilliamJones